# storing application data in metro application C#

Tags: c#, database, microsoft-metro, storage

I'm totally new to Windows 8 programming and I am writing Diary application for Windows 8 on C# right now. It stores diary's notes which user writes. The question is following: how do I store this notes so that user (and program) can easily access any of them via dates? I've thought of storing each of them in a separate file or all of them in one, but this seems not a good idea for me. Using some sort of local database would be nice, but is there anything like this among inbuilt Metro development tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite as your database: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx